# Unidirectional OneToMany using Foreign Key Column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to maintain ACL information for each of my entities. For this i have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class ACLEntry {
  ...
  @Id
  private Long id;

  private Long sid;

  private Integer permissionMask;
}
```

The entity for which the acl information should be maintained looks like the following:

```
@Entity
public class Folder {
  ...

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="entity_id")
  private List<ACLEntry> aclEntries;
}
```

From the hibernate docs:

> A unidirectional one to many using a foreign key column in the owned entity is not that common
>   and not really recommended

Why is this not recommended and why should i use a jointable ?

Is there a better way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

ACLEntry should have a reference to parent Folder @ManyToOne

Comment: I've multiple entities for which the acl information should be maintained and with @ManyToOne i can only reference only entity i think